# Wordpress Pages not showing any content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed WordPress 4.5.3 and have built my custom theme. Everything works pretty well except for the fact that some pages don't show any content at all. I have tried to search on how to fix this but I can't find any solution, because my own problem has pages that don't even enter 'the loop'. I have tried to echo things within the loop to make sure that it enters but to no avail. My theme is still offline so i could not provide a link to it. Please any idea why it is not entering the loop.

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<style type="text/css">
  .submit input {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #f88b0c;
  }
</style>
<div class="row">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
    <h2 class="title ">
   <center>
    <?the_title()?>
    <hr>
   </center>
  </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail())?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: None of the pages work? Or just some?

Comment: only one page. what happens is when i am composing on hat page article and preview it, it appears correctly, but once i save it nothing appears